# datatables - Custom filter and pagination

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination, datatables

I have created custom filter for my DataTables:

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var row = table.row(dataIndex).node();

        if (checked) {
            if ($(row).data('distributed') == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });

    table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

And it's working fine but with one exception - pagination. When I apply this filter I have returned only first page, nothing more.

Here is my DataTable init:

```
var table = $('#invitation__table').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    pageLength: 50,
    deferRender: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('datatables', ['weekend' => $weekend, 'type' => $type]) !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'names', name: 'names' },
        { data: 'invitation_type', name: 'invitation_type' },
        { data: 'exhibitor', name: 'exhibitor' },
        { data: 'contact', name: 'contact' },
        { data: 'custom_access', name: 'custom_access', className: 'text-center' },
        { data: 'vip_room', name: 'vip_room', className: 'text-center' },
        { data: 'status', name: 'status', className: 'text-center' }
    ]
});
```

**Filter conception**

```
if(checkboxIsChecked) {
  if(rowHasDataAttributeWithValue == 1) {
    // hide this row
  }
} else {
   // show all rows
}
```

Comment: Because you are removing the filter immediately by    `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();`

Comment: @davidkonrad I removed it and still not working, showing (xxxx) total records but showing only filtered first page

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for tip, I applied it ;) But still problem with this pagination :(

Comment: `if ($(row).data('distributed') == 0) {` does not make sense as standalone. You take the DOM node, typecast it to a jQuery array, looking for a jQuery data item? Something is certainly missing in your question. The filter will return all or none rows, based on the value of `checked`, for nowhere in the initialisation you are adding jQuery data values.

Comment: Cannot debug none existing code, but try comment out `deferRender: true,` if you insist that the filter is actually working, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: `deferRender` was the problem, thanks! You can make answer with this, I'll accept it :) I have updated question for my concept for this filter if you want :)

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself (and remember to mark it as accepted) I just had a hunch, I am sure an answer could help future visitors! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @davidkonrad for help, the problem was:

```
deferRender: true
```

Comment out it and works fine :)